# sqlsrv_connect db Connect

Tags: php, sql-server

i am trying to make a connection between php and mssql via sqlsrv_connect on wamp server, after transferring the .dll file to php ext. folder i made changes in my php.ini file.

i restart the server and check on the tray: wamp tray => php => extensions, and php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts and php_sqlsrv_55_nts are ticked good, but when i check  phpinfo on my web browser i cant seems to find anything regarding sqlsrv.

and if i try
`<?php`

`//connection to the database`
`$serverName = 'servername';`
`$connectDetails = array('Database' => 'dbname');`
`$connect = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectDetails );`
`if($connect){`
    `echo 'connected';`
    `}else{`
        `echo 'connection failed';`
        `die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));`
    `}`

`?>`
i get this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\baze\sitename.php on line 6.

please does any1 know why i keep getting this error?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you need the **ts** version. Because its Thread Safe. If you use the nts version the extension is not loaded and you can't use it.

For more informations make a `phpinfo();` and you should find the module in your output.

Comment: thanks for the response **Stony** but the thing is, i cant find anything on phpinfo(),even after making the correction you propose. i was reading elsewhere i learnt its because i am using the 64bit version of wamp. wanna give that a try.

Comment: 64bit is a problem. Most modules are not compiled in 64bit. http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqldriverforphp.aspx?ID=73a97526-8aa9-4281-8a9a-0eb396e1350c